# Is it a bad practice to use a ThreadLocal Object for storing web request metadata?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, thread-local

I am working on a j2ee webapp divided in several modules. I have some metadata such as user name and preferences that I would like to access from everywhere in the app, and maybe also gather data similar to logging information but specific to a request and store it in those metadata so that I could optionally send it back as debug information to the user.

Aside from passing a generic context object throughout every method from the upper presentation classes to the downer daos or using AOP, the only solution that came in mind was using a threadlocal "Context" object very similar to a session BTW, and add a filter for binding it on ongoing request and unbinding it on response.

But such thing feels a little hacky since this breaks several patterns and could possibly make things complicated when it comes to testing and debugging so I wanted to ask if from your experience it is ok to proceed like this?

Comment: (I know this is old. but ..still) Do not ask in internet if something is a bad practice. People will tell you 1000 things. Some of the people here might not even have developed the same type of application you are developing. Please do a simple POC and try yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes to testing, the best tool is dependency injection. It allows to inject fake dependencies into the object under test.

And all dependency injection frameworks (Spring, CDI, Guice) have the concept of a scope (where request is one of these scopes). Under the hood, beans stored in the request scoped are indeed associated with a ThreadLocal variable, but this is all done by the dependency injection framework.

What I would do is thus to use a DI framework, which would make request-scope objects available anywhere, but without having to look them up, which would break testability. Just inject a request-scoped object where you want to use it, and the DI framework will retrieve it for you.

Comment: I am already familiar with DI frameworks and using spring in this case, but never thought about using a request-scoped bean for that purpose, it opens new perspectives. I just regret having to inject the bean so many times. Since the current policy in my company is to not using annotation but configuration files it will add a lot of flood in the xml

Comment: Additionally, I can easily declare a ThreadLocal inside a filter I would declare in my web.xml, but how do I inject something in the filter? Because my application is JSF, my methods are called from a lot of points and I don't see where I would initialize that request-scope object but in a request filter

Comment: Regarding XML: I can feel the pain. Annotation-based DI is so much better. Regarding filters, you can use a [DelegatingFilterProxy](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html), or replace the filter by a [HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor). But I repeat: you don't need any ThreadLocal. Just a request-scoped bean. The ThreadLocal dirty handling will be handled by Spring.

Answer (score 7):

Personally I prefer passing a context object, as the fact that the same thread is used for processing is an artifact of the implementation, and you shouldn't rely on such artifacts. The moment you want to use other threads, you'll hit a wall.

If those states are encapsulated in a Context object, I think that's clean enough.

Comment: But how do you access that Context object from the code? Do every method of your interfaces take a Context object as one of their arguments? As for using several Threads each can have its own Context object and I can list them from the parent.

Comment: It would be great if you could expand your answer to address the questions raised by @Aldian

Comment: @Aldian: personally I think it's fine if you are passing around context objects. If it really gets out of hand you can create a new object with the context as field and do your complex thing. I think using `ThreadLocal` would make code harder to understand.

Answer (score 7):

ThreadLocal is a hack to make up for bad design and/or architecture. It's a terrible practice:

1. It's a pool of one or more global variables and global variables in any language are bad practice (there's a whole set of problems associated with global variables - search it on the net)
2. It may lead to memory leaks, in any J2EE container than manages its threads, if you don't handle it well.

What's even worse practice is to use the ThreadLocal in the various layers.
Data communicated from one layer to another should be passed using Transfer Objects (a standard pattern).

It's hard to think of a good justification for using ThreadLocal. Perhaps if you need to communicate some values between 2 layers that have a third/middle layer between them, and you don't have the means to make changes to that middle layer. But if that's the case, I would look for a better middle layer.
In any case, if you store the values in one specific point in the code and retrieve it in another single point, then it may be excusable, otherwise you just never know what side affects any executing method may have on the values in the ThreadLocal.

Answer (score 2):

If you are the only developer in the project and you think you gain something: just do it! Because it is your time. But, be prepared to revert the decision and reorganize the code base later, as should be always the case.

Let's say there are ten developers on the project. Everybody might like to have its thread local variable to pass on parameters like currency, locale, roles, maybe it becomes even a HashMap....

I think in the end, not everything which is feasible, should be done. Complexity will strike back on you....

Comment: I like your advice. Instead of saying "very very bad design blah blah.." etc. Nothing is bad when you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

You must know that a servlet container can / will re-use threads for requests so if you do use ThreadLocals, you'll need to clean up after yourself once the request is finished (perhaps using a filter)

Comment: That was already planned. In fact I was much concerned by the potential memory leak if I didn't, but that is en even better reason

Comment: With ThreadLocal you will potentially have data leak, not memory.

Answer (score 0):

ThreadLocal can lead to memory leak if we do not set null manually once its out of scope.